# Symfony 2 Override registration controller and display errors on the same page without redirecting to /register or without clearing form data

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

I am using the FOSUserBundle. Basically I overrided the registration controller and handler, and i  created a customised registration form. What I want to do is to stay on the same page if there's an error during registration failure.

I managed to stay on the same page but the form reloads but doesn't show the error.

So basically how can I generate these errors while staying on the page without clearing the form fields.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Try this one. Call the form_errors so it prompts the error message within your registration page.

```
<form id="sign_up" action="{{ path('your_registration_route') }}"  method="POST">
{{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
<button class="btn" type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}">SIGN UP</button>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Comment: Does my answer didn't work? Pls leave a comment for any question